# Is there a method to apply javascript on sprite.svg file components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, gsap

I have a **bundle of SVG components** in my **sprite.SVG file** and an **HTML page** where I am including those SVG components here in HTML.
eg:

```
<svg class="svg-icon">
      <use xlink:href="sprite.svg#hiw-svg"></use>
</svg>
```

Now , I want to **apply javascript** on the **components of svg's** which I included, So how should I do that, since those components are defined in sprite.svg file.

One possible solution is that I include those sprite symbols directly as svg in my html but I don't want to do that as I have lots of svg's which will take lot of space in html.

**So what is is the best way I can apply GreenSock js or simply (JS) for animations on sprite.svg file.**

Comment: The *only* way to animate them via JS is if you have access to the DOM nodes, i.e. they are inlined SVG. Why *not* include them inline? You load the same amount of data either way...

Comment: @ZachSaucier he can place like `<object>`, waiting till svg loaded and get access with `contentDocument`

Answer (score -1):

There's a way to use javascript inside the svg when using an object tag to embed svg.

Here's an example of embedding the javascript animation inside the svg file itself.

https://codesandbox.io/s/inline-svg-javascript-with-object-iy2mq?file=/index.html

Comment: But there's no object tag here. This embedding is via use